# OnClicklistener in RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, methods, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to get an OnClickListener in my RecyclerView but I can't get it to work.
I try to access the method "setOnItemClickListener" from my Activity.
The method is created in my Adapter:

```
public class HauptgerichteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HauptgerichteAdapter.HauptgerichtViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<HauptgerichtItem> mHauptgerichtList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }
```

and I try to acces it in my Activity in OnCreate :

```
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHauptgerichte);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new HauptgerichteAdapter(Hauptgerichte.this,hauptgerichtList);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(Hauptgerichte.this);
```

But it just marks the setOnItemClickListener red and it says "Cannot resolve method 'setOnItemClickListener' in 'Adapter'".

Heres the full Adapter if that helps anything

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HauptgerichteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HauptgerichteAdapter.HauptgerichtViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<HauptgerichtItem> mHauptgerichtList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private Context mContext;
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public class HauptgerichtViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mtitleView;
        public TextView mVegetarischView;
        public TextView mVeganView;
        public TextView mTimeView;



        public HauptgerichtViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewGericht);
            mtitleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewtitle);
            mVegetarischView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTag1);
            mVeganView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTag2);
            mTimeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mListener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            mListener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                    // RecyclerView Tutorial Part 6 2:56
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public HauptgerichteAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HauptgerichtItem> hauptgerichtList){
        mHauptgerichtList = hauptgerichtList;
        mContext = context;
}
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HauptgerichtViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hauptgericht_item,parent,false);
        HauptgerichtViewHolder hvh = new HauptgerichtViewHolder(v);

        return hvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HauptgerichtViewHolder holder, int position) {
    HauptgerichtItem currentItem = mHauptgerichtList.get(position);

    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getmImageResource());
    holder.mtitleView.setText(currentItem.getmTitle());
    holder.mVegetarischView.setText(currentItem.getmTagVegetarisch());
    holder.mVeganView.setText(currentItem.getmTagVegan());
    holder.mTimeView.setText(currentItem.getmTime());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mHauptgerichtList.size();
    }

}
```

If you need anything else, let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `mAdapter` would need to be declared as a `HauptgerichteAdapter`, not just `Recycler.Adapter`.

Comment: Thanks Mike M.! I had declared it wrong! It seems so simple jet i was looking for so long.